# Insert json in mysql database using php in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I am getting this response from an android app in JSON, I want to fetch the response and insert each data as a single row below down is my JSON response model and controller thanks in advance

**Response**

```
{
    "DEALS": [{
        "ORDER_DATE": "2020-09-06 03:31:23 PM",
        "CUSTOMER_ID": "umersaleem_03334033313",
        "QUANTITY": 1,
        "DEAL_ID": "3",
        "ORDER_TOTAL": "2100.0"
    }, {
        "ORDER_DATE": "2020-09-06 03:31:23 PM",
        "CUSTOMER_ID": "umersaleem_03334033313",
        "QUANTITY": 1,
        "DEAL_ID": "3",
        "ORDER_TOTAL": "2100.0"
    }]
}
```

**controller**

```
        $reponse=array();
 $this->db->trans_begin();
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $filter_data = array(
            'ORDER_DATE'=> $order_date,
            'CUSTOMER_ID' => $customer_id,
            'PRODUCT_ID' => $product_id,
            'QUANTITY' => $quantity,
            'DEAL_ID' => $deal_id,
            'ORDER_TOTAL' => $order_total,
        );
       //Call the save method
       $this->Order_model->insertorderinfo($filter_data);
    }

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        echo json_encode("Failed to Save Data");
    } else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        echo json_encode("Success!");
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function insertorderinfo($data) {
    $this->db->insert('ORDER_INFO', $data);
}
```

Comment: `foreach($data['DEALS'] as` or `foreach($data->DEALS as` depending what it is

Comment: then `$row['ORDER_DATE']` not `$order_date`.. just basic looping over an object/array

Comment: your missing `$product_id` too

Comment: ..and ORDER_DATE its not a valid datetime format, your need fix that before insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php
$test_json='{"DEALS":[{"ORDER_DATE":"2020-09-06 03:31:23 PM","CUSTOMER_ID":"umersaleem_03334033313","QUANTITY":1,"DEAL_ID":"3","ORDER_TOTAL":"2100.0"},{"ORDER_DATE":"2020-09-06 03:31:23 PM","CUSTOMER_ID":"umersaleem_03334033313","QUANTITY":1,"DEAL_ID":"3","ORDER_TOTAL":"2100.0"}]}';

$json=(json_decode($test_json, true));

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    // get count as in key there is deals
    $total_order=count($value);
    for($i=0; $i<$total_order; $i++){
        echo $value[$i]['ORDER_DATE']."<br />";
        echo $value[$i]['CUSTOMER_ID']."<br />";
        echo $value[$i]['QUANTITY']."<br />";
        echo $value[$i]['DEAL_ID']."<br />";
        echo $value[$i]['ORDER_TOTAL']."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: how to pass it to model to insert in databases?

Comment: $this->Order_model->insertorderinfo($filter_data); add this in foreach loop or for loop

Comment: and if i want to get json from url instead or hard coded json?

Comment: does it matter? in any ways you can use it that json i mean from url just $_Get json decode it and use foreach or pass it in varible like this $json=$_GET['json'] ; and use it. or whatever ways you use it to get data from url. just use one varible to define that json thats it